# Showing martingale property of a series

Tags: probability, martingales, conditional-expectation

I want to show that the following series is a martingale.

$P(X_1=1)=P(X_2=-1)=0.5$ and

$P(X_i=X_{i-1})=p$  and $ P(X_i=-X_{i-1})=1-p$

$S_n=X_1+...+X_{n-1}+\frac{1}{2(1-p)}X_n$

We need to show that:

$E[S_{n+1}|\mathcal{F}_{n}]=S_{n}$

Comment: You might want to apply the answer to your previous answer, to this setting.

Comment: @Did I tried that, couldn't do it, this is why I asked. You might want to help?

Comment: Please leave more information on why you could not apply the previous answer. Just where are you stuck?

Comment: To be clear, I am alluding to [this accepted answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1046290). If really you cannot apply it to the present case, this is problematic, to the point that one can wonder whether you understood it at all. Did you?

Comment: @Did, yes I did understand it, my problem was, I didn't know how to partition the $S_{n+1}$, but I think I got it now, I edited my question.

Comment: Right, so... a direct application of the other answer. In this context, what do you think of your reaction to my first comment?

Comment: @Did That it was rude. I apologize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I did it:

$S_{n+1}=X_1+...+\frac{1}{2(1-p)}X_{n}+ \frac{2(1-p)-1}{2(1-p)}X_n+\frac{1}{2(1-p)}X_{n+1}=$

$=S_n+\frac{2(1-p)-1}{2(1-p)}X_n+\frac{1}{2(1-p)}X_{n+1}$

Then the conditional expectation:

$E[S_{n+1}|\mathcal{F}_{n}]= E[S_n+\frac{2(1-p)-1}{2(1-p)}X_n+\frac{1}{2(1-p)}X_{n+1}|\mathcal{F}_n]=$

$=S_n+\frac{2(1-p)-1}{2(1-p)}X_n+\frac{1}{2(1-p)}E[X_{n+1}|\mathcal{F}_n]=$

$=S_n+\frac{2(1-p)-1}{2(1-p)}X_n+\frac{1}{2(1-p)}(2p-1)X_n$

$=S_n+\frac{1-2p}{2(1-p)}X_n-\frac{1-2p}{2(1-p)}X_n=S_n$